# I am looking to use textfiles to validate a username and password login

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to use textfiles to validate a username and password in VB.NET.

I have the username validated but I can not validate the passsword and anything entered in txtpassowrd.text will result in a login.

The code I used is this:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class frmReceptionist
    Function IsInFile(ByVal person As String) As Boolean
        If File.Exists("receptionistUser.txt") And File.Exists("receptionistPassword.txt") Then

            Dim sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText("receptionistUser.txt")
            Dim individual As String

            Do Until sr.EndOfStream
                individual = sr.ReadLine

                If individual = person Then
                    sr.Close()
                    Return True
                End If

            Loop
            sr.Close()
        End If
        Return False

    End Function

    Private Sub btnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click
        'Determine if a person is in the file
        Dim person As String = txtUsername.Text

        If person <> "" Then
            If IsInFile(person) Then

                MessageBox.Show(person & " Welcome Receptionist", "Bia Duitse")
                Me.Hide()
                frmBiaDuitse.Show()

            Else
                MessageBox.Show(person & " Incorrect Login", "No")

            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter Details", "Information")
        End If
        txtUsername.Clear()
        txtUsername.Focus()

    End Sub
    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.Hide()
        frmSelectJob.Show()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: First I should tell you that this is probably the most insecure way to store users and passwords. But if you really insist to use this way then you should have a single file where, on the same line of the user name, you have also the relative password eventually separating the two informations with some kind of special character that you can use to split the info when retrieving the lines

Comment: I assume this is just some kind of demo / mockup? Your user can just open the text file on their disk using Notepad and view all the passwords. It doesn't provide any real security. BTW you don't need two files for this, just use a CSV file with `username,password` on each line, so the usernames and passwords are paired. Otherwise you have no way to know which password belongs to which user, and I think this is part of the problem in your code (also, at the moment you never seem to actually read anything from the password file at all, you don't even try to check it!).

Comment: P.S. Perhaps for a tiny bit of safety you could hash the passwords and then hard-code the hashing method etc into your app code, so at least it's obfuscated - although someone could still try to decompile the code to find the hashing info. But it's still basically useless as real security.

Comment: Good answers so far, What I would do is have a fixed length record (structure) containing a fixed length username and a fixed length hash of the password, this is more secure, then you can simply read the records sequentially and compare the username against the hashed password inputted. File size would be calculable and updating usernames and passwords would the a thousand times easier.

Answer (score 0):

**This is definitely not the way you should be doing this.**

For learning purposes, you could load up your files into a Dictionary() like this:

```
Private Credentials As Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub LoadCredentials()
    If IsNothing(Credentials) Then
        Credentials = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
        If File.Exists("receptionistUser.txt") And File.Exists("receptionistPassword.txt") Then
            Dim users() As String = File.ReadAllLines("receptionistUser.txt")
            Dim passwords() As String = File.ReadAllLines("receptionistPassword.txt")
            If users.Length = passwords.Length Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To users.Length - 1
                    Credentials.Add(users(i), passwords(i))
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function IsInFile(ByVal person As String) As Boolean
    LoadCredentials()
    If Not IsNothing(Credentials) Then
        Return Credentials.ContainsKey(person)
    End If
    Return False
End Function

Function Checkpassword(ByVal person As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean
    LoadCredentials()
    If Not IsNothing(Credentials) Then
        Return Credentials.ContainsKey(person) AndAlso password = Credentials(person)
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```